# Accurately load WinForm every time it gets focus or gets created

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, refresh

I'm trying to simply get a form to load correctly. It is a modeless child form of a modal parent (which itself is a modeless child form of the main UI). I need to be able to interact with all forms somewhat simultaneously.

The form I want to reload has very little access by way of fixed controls. Mostly dynamic controls loaded from reading a text file (users) and placing checkboxes (1 per user in the text file in columns) on the form.

The first thing I need to do is simply to write the form accurately every time. I open the form with a button, but retain ownership to the parent. If the parent closes, all of the children should close (but not the program. The parent of this child, is a child). Ex:

```
    private void bPermissions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Permissions af3 = new Permissions();
        af3.Owner = this;
        af3.Show();
    }
```

So I click the button Permissions and the form opens accurately. If I select it again, the form opens without the checkboxes. If I close Permissions and then try to reopen it, it does not load accurately. Only the fixed items load. I've tried to .Refresh() the parent form and the child form in various events (FormClosed, FormClosing, Load, etc.) on both the Start form and the Permissions form.

How can I refresh this form accurately every time I try to open it?

EDIT:

I'm a newb and very much enjoy doing this. But I am learning. Please be kind and point me in a direction. :-D Thank You.

EDIT2: Not modal. Modeless.

Comment: I think your issue may be in the Permissions Form.  When in that form do you create the controls?  You are creating a new version of that form each time you click the button... so the child form is probably where the difference is.

Comment: Just a note: `Modeless` form is opened when calling `frm.Show()` and `Modal` when `frm.ShowDialog()`

Comment: I'm creating the controls at Permissions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {WidgetLogic.getPermText(this);} \*Where this is a reference to System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm*\ in Permissions.cs by feeding them from a logic file. . Hmmm... I've tried putting the refresh() in the sender when Start loses focus at Leave. Maybe the refresh() should be in the Start.cs at some other location?

Comment: @Reniuz Correct. Edited. Thank You. Modeless

Comment: @D.. Brilliant!! I made the call to the logic and referenced af3 instead of making the call to the logic onLoad and it works perfect everytime. Thank You So Much!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. @D.. definitely led me down the path. As a Newb I promise I had to do a little head scratching.

I was making the call from onLoad

```
    private void Permissions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WidgetLogic.getPermText(this);
        WidgetLogic.getDetailerPermText(this);
        WidgetLogic.getAdminPermText(this);
    }
```

I should have been making the call from the button prior to the page loading and passing it back from the logic to the targetForm. The form where I wanted the information to go (Permissions af3)

```
    private void bPermissions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Permissions af3 = new Permissions();
        af3.Owner = this;
        af3.Show();
        WidgetLogic.getPermText(af3);
        WidgetLogic.getDetailerPermText(af3);
        WidgetLogic.getAdminPermText(af3);
    }
```

Awesome Sauce!! :-D Thank You!!